# Alterar cor de um Button que já possui um Background atribuído

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Olá, no meu aplicativo tem uma tabela (Alert Dialog) que será usada para selecionar a cor de um componente. Nessa tabela existem vários botões iguais com o background já definido para que eles fiquem com um estilo redondo. Para isso, eu usei um arquivo XML com a propriedade ***shape***.

Eu queria que cada um desses botões tivesse uma cor diferente. Porém, não quero criar vários arquivos XML definindo a cor de cada um. Quero saber se tem algum modo diferente de alterar a cor sem mexer no seu background, ou até mesmo alterar a cor do ***shape*** do botão.

Eu também aceito sugestões para fazer essa tabela de um jeito diferente, sem precisar usar um monte de botões.

Arquivo XML para background dos botões:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
        />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se `minSdkVersion` >= 21 use

```
android:backgroundTint
```

Para versões inferiores, altere a cor do `solid` para `#FFFFFF` e use o seguinte codigo para colocar a cor que pretende,

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
Drawable background = button.getBackground();
background.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Se quer uma alternativa a um layout "cheio de botões" veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68694/2541). Nela é usado um Spinner para escolher a cor, mas o mesmo *adapter*  pode ser usado numa ListView.

Comment: A segunda opção funcionou perfeitamente pra mim, muito obrigado!